# How to delete a specific value in a column with vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete a specific value in a column with vba.

Here is my code for now. But of course it is not working.

```
   vstd = Range("J6").Offset(l - 1, 0).Value


      For Each Rng2 In Range("F6:F2555")
       If Rng2.Value = vstd Then
       Rng2.ClearContents
      End If
   Next
```

Comment: Needs an "End IF" after the clearcontents

Comment: `But of course it is not working.` is very vague.  Can you specify the error?

Comment: Also, do you have something like `Sub clearCellContents()` at the start, and `End Sub` at the end? You have to place the code within a `Sub`, not just o its own.

Comment: Edited the code ı add End If but still doesnt work

Comment: ı have sub and end sub.

Comment: What does it do that is in error, or what error pops up when you run it?  `Doesn't work` is not specific enough for us to help.  Please be more specific with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you're looking for?

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim vSpecificVal As Variant
    vSpecificVal = Range("J6").Offset(l - 1, 0).Value

    Call Range("F6:F2555").Replace(vSpecificVal, "")

End Sub
```

Please let us know thanks

Comment: to make your example really effective 1) you should specify at least `lookAt:=xlWhole` parameter and be sure it's not going to delete cells simply _containing_ the wanted values. But it's safer to specify all parameters since _"The settings for LookAt, SearchOrder, MatchCase, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method"_ 2) you should add `Dim l As Long` and some `l=someLongValue` 3) finally you could avoid `Call` and take off parenthesis after `Replace` like follows: `Range("F6:F2555").Replace what:=vSpecificVal, replacement:="", lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True`

Answer (score 0):

here's an `AutoFilter()` approach:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ClearColumn()
    Dim l As Long

    l = 1 '<--| initializing 'l' variable value
    With Range("F5:F2555") '<--| reference your range
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("J6").Offset(l - 1, 0).Value '<--| filter on value in cell offsetted "l-1" rows from J6
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents '<--| if any filtered cell found clear their contents
    End With
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

be sure that you initialize `l` values so as not to have `Range("J6").Offset(l - 1, 0)` reference an invalid Range (i.e. `l` must be less than 6)